# alternative rake task to heroku worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to find a solution to run a background task on heroku every few hours, without the need to pay for an expensive worker.

So far, I have implemented a rails controller with a specific def which it invokes the job.
So, whenever I hit the url, it runs normally. Now I'm trying to find a solution to hit this url every few hours.

Of course, I could run a cron task from another server with something like

`/usr/bin/curl -s "http://url/of/hourly/task" > /dev/null`

or simply use a webcron service, but I would like some more control.
I tried the `whenever` gem https://github.com/javan/whenever on a second rails application, but I could not make it run properly. I'm new in ruby anyway.
Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: But you know that when you use Heroku Scheduler worker will run only as long as needed and is billed per second? So if you use free plan and your app will run even 10 minutes er day then it still be free!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Heroku Scheduler`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) addon. It can run your jobs every 10 minutes, every hour, or every day, at a specified time.

Comment: And I was wondering why heroku provides for a web dyno, more hours than the hours of a month :)

Comment: Yeah, also `heroku run console` is counted :)